# mod_rewrite for mobiles using a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile

I have a site that can allow me to access the mobile version of the site via a query in the URL.

What I can't figure out is how to automatically redirect mobile users to this version (currently you have to add '?useformat=mobile' in order to view).

This is my current htaccess setup

```
RewriteEngine On

#MediaWiki short URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#Mobile - not working?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?useformat=mobile&title=$1 [L]

#HTTPS redirect (site uses HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Kinda new to mod_rewrite, not done much with it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this above your mobile rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And you need to move your mobile rules above the mediawiki rules because it's rewriting before the mobile rules get applied, and then you need to move the HTTPS rules above that. So together, it should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#HTTPS redirect (site uses HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#Mobile - not working?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?useformat=mobile&title=$1 [L]

#MediaWiki short URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Also add the QSA flag to the mobile rule.

Comment: Works great, however it does not run through HTTPS if I make it the first rule. Put it last and it works just how I want it. Also adding QSA causes e500